make the live visitor counter change without refresh
My client want to make total visitor counter.
Is it possible to make the total visitor counter increase but when the user not refresh the page? so the users can see the total visitor increasing without refresh the page. What should i add to make it happen? Please kindly explain in detail because i am new to typescript.
here's my code
type visitortype={
  count: number;
}


const Footer = () => {
  const [visitor, setvisitor] = useState<visitortype>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(allvisitor=>  setvisitor(allvisitor))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);

 return (
    <GridItem
      w="100%"
      h={{ base: "80px", lg: "300px" }}
      colSpan={{ base: 8, lg: 4 }}
    >
      <VStack
        align={{ base: "center", lg: "stretch" }}
        marginTop={{ base: "0", lg: "60px" }}
        marginLeft={{ base: "0", lg: "50px" }}
      >
        <Box w={{ base: "100px", lg: "220px" }} paddingBottom={"10px"}>
          <Image src={imgLogoMd} alt="Logo" w="100%" />
          <HStack>
            <Text fontSize={{ base: "xs", lg: "md" }} textAlign={"justify"}>
              {visitor?.count} Visitor
            </Text>
          </HStack>
        </Box>
      </VStack>
    </GridItem>
  );

};


You can look into Web Sockets:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket
You can also look into applying a setInterval perhaps to "poll" for changes.
Found this:
How to setInterval for every 5 second render with React hook useEffect in React Native app?
Note the clear interval part.

There are several strategies how you can get live or close to live counter:

Just poll your api every interval of your choice to get fresh stats. Super-simple to implement.
Long polling, probably 2nd-simple to implement but requires modifications on the backend
Use server side events
Use websockets via library, for example socket.io or sockjs

Only the first method not require any modifications on the backend, and most likely would be sufficient in your case. You just need to add a hook that will let you repeatedly poll an api: useInterval
Here is how it might look like

import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';

type CallbackType = (...args: any[]) => any;

// first you will need useInterval hook, you can implement it yourself or grab it from the lib. 
export function useInterval(callback: CallbackType, delay: number) { 
  const savedCallback = useRef<CallbackType | undefined>(); 
  useEffect(() => { 
    savedCallback.current = callback; 
  }, [callback]); 
  
  useEffect(() => { 
    function func() { 
      savedCallback.current?.(); 
    } 
    if (delay !== null) { 
      let id = setInterval(func, delay); 
      return () => clearInterval(id); 
    } 
  }, [delay]); 
}

// let's say we would like to get fresh stats every minute
const REFRESH_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000

const Footer = () => {
  const [visitor, setVisitor] = useState<visitortype>();

  useInterval(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b')
      const data = await response.json()
      setVisitor(data);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, REFRESH_INTERVAL);

 return (
    <GridItem
      w="100%"
      h={{ base: "80px", lg: "300px" }}
      colSpan={{ base: 8, lg: 4 }}
    >
      <VStack
        align={{ base: "center", lg: "stretch" }}
        marginTop={{ base: "0", lg: "60px" }}
        marginLeft={{ base: "0", lg: "50px" }}
      >
        <Box w={{ base: "100px", lg: "220px" }} paddingBottom={"10px"}>
          <Image src={imgLogoMd} alt="Logo" w="100%" />
          <HStack>
            <Text fontSize={{ base: "xs", lg: "md" }} textAlign={"justify"}>
              {visitor?.count} Visitor
            </Text>
          </HStack>
        </Box>
      </VStack>
    </GridItem>
  );

};



its get error for savedCallback.current = callback;   "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'." and error setVisitor(allvisitor);  "Cannot find name 'allvisitor'. Did you mean 'visitor'?"

ah, fixed both errors

still error for savedCallback.current?.();  "This expression is not callable.
Type 'never' has no call signatures."

well, i guess you need to add type definitions to useInterval. i fixed

sorry but result just the same and add new error for savedCallback.current = callback;  "Type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'undefined'."

ahaha) ok, lets add the same type definition to useRef then. try now :)

so sorry its keep error TypeError: Duplicate declaration "useInterval" and Cannot find name 'CallbackType'.

The web client-server architecture is essentially based on the principle that only clients initiate requests.
Therefore the main solution to have a regular update without needing the visitor to manually take action every time, is to programmatically launch new requests at some pre-determined interval.
Here in React you can use e.g. useInterval hook from react-use:
import { useInterval } from 'react-use';

useInterval(
  () => {
    fetch('https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(allvisitor=>  setvisitor(allvisitor))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  },
  10_000 // Delay in milliseconds, e.g. here every 10 seconds
);


There are now more advanced ways to have a "live" connection between client and server that enable escaping from the original client-initiated request only scheme, like WebSockets (as mentionned in David's answer) and Server Events, but that would require to configure the server accordingly.

getting error  "Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3."

Sorry my bad, I fixed the example.

its still not quite right ,first when page refresh its not showing but after every 10 second its the total keep increasing even i the only one open the page. how to solve this?

"the total keep increasing": that is the behaviour of your API endpoint, directly open your URL and refresh to see it. There is no cutting on changing your server behaviour somehow if you want it to behave differently.
